# how not to generate maven jar

Tags: java, maven

This is my project structure

```
parent project - pom.xml
|
|----------> simple-math -- pom.xml
|----------> simple-web -- pom.xml
```

simple-math gives a function called App.add(a,b) which adds two numbers.

simple-web used this App.add and displays it in index.jsp

Its working beautifully with default settings that is with jar and war.

What i would like to do is not let simple-math produce jar, instead make them produce plain old class files. and simple-web calls Add with .class path than jar

What changes should i make in pom.xml -- simple-math
how should I execute this from parent project?

Answer (score 0):

The philosophy of Maven is to produce just one main artefact for a project. A project typically contains more than one class so packaging them up into a jar makes sense.

Another reason for doing that is that an artifact you deploy into a repository gets the version number into its name. You could not do that with a class file.

If you really want to have the individual class files in your war you can try to expand the simple-math-{version}.jar during the build of the simple-web project.